# Map three rows of data into a matrix

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a dataset of movies ratings that looks as follow:

[image]

I want to map this into a matrix where the index in the user id, columns are the moviesids and values are the ratings.

What I have done so far is:

```
movies = df['movieId'].unique()
users = df['userId'].unique()
data_set = pd.DataFrame({'userId':users})
data_set = data_set.set_index('userId')
for movie in movies:
    data_set[movie] = 0
```

[image]

So now I need to fill those spaces items with the corresponding ratings, but this is a messy and slow process.

Comment: Try: `df.pivot(index='userId', columns='movieId', values='rating')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        [1, 11, 1],
        [1, 12, 5],
        [2, 11, 3],
        [2, 13, 4]
    ], columns=['userid', 'movieid', 'rating'])
```

***option 1***
`pivot`

```
df.pivot('userid', 'movieid', 'rating')
```

***option 2***
`set_index` + `unstack`

```
df.set_index(['userid', 'movieid']).rating.unstack()
```

---

Both yield

```
movieid   11   12   13
userid                
1        1.0  5.0  NaN
2        3.0  NaN  4.0
```

---

However, the `unstack` method has a `fill_value` parameter that allows to keep the integer dtype

```
df.set_index(['userid', 'movieid']).rating.unstack(fill_value=0)

movieid  11  12  13
userid             
1         1   5   0
2         3   0   4
```